# When select change write in session

Tags: php, html, session

I am writing a function for changing the language on my site. How do I set: if language selection changes, than refresh page.

As in: `if(value=="ru"){$_SESSION["lang"]="ru"; Refresh page}`

in:

```
<select  class="leng" name="language" id="language" >               
                <option selected="selected" value="en">en</option>
                <option value="ru" >ru</option>
                <option value="ae">ae</option>
                <option value="bg">bg</option>

            </select>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have this in a form with a `name` attribute, something like:

```
<form name='formname' method='post' action='handlelanguage.php'>
  <select  class="leng" name="language" id="language" onChange="document.formname.submit()">
```

Then in that page something like:

```
$value = $_POST['language'];
if($value=='ru')
{
  $_SESSION["lang"] = "ru"; 
  header('Location: originalpage.php');
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is some old-school javascript solution without using forms:

```
<select class="leng" name="language" id="language" onChange="document.location.href='your_page.php?lang=' + this.value">
    <option selected="selected" value="en">en</option>
    <option value="ru">ru</option>
    <option value="ae">ae</option>
    <option value="bg">bg</option>
</select>
```

and on "your_page.php":

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_GET["lang"])) $_SESSION["lang"] = $_GET["lang"];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting a session variable, there's no need to refresh the page since the processing is happening before the headers are sent. You simply need to post the form to the page you want to set the session variable, like this:

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
  
  <select  class="leng" name="language" id="language" >               
    <option selected="selected" value="en">en</option>
    <option value="ru" >ru</option>
    <option value="ae">ae</option>
    <option value="bg">bg</option>
  </select>  

  <input type="submit" />
  
</form>
```

Then, before that code you would want to add some PHP like this (make sure this takes places before *any* other output or you will get a PHP error):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['language'])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['language'];
}
?>
```

At this point, the session variable has been saved from your form that posted to the same page. You can take more action accordingly.